# Bash script to execute command with file from directory and condition

Tags: shell-script

I'd like to sort my figlet fonts with testing, so I've decided to make a script, which will demonstrate figlet font one by one and will delete fonts I don't like. 
I've tried to find the solution for correct if-then condition inside while loop, but couldn't find one.
Here's the script itself, but for now it just provides examples of all the fonts in the single scroll:

```
#!/bin/bash
#script to test figlet fonts
rm /usr/share/figlet/list.txt #delete old list
ls /usr/share/figlet > /usr/share/figlet/list.txt #create new list
filename='/usr/share/figlet/list.txt'
n=1
while read line; do
    figlet -f $line Figlet
    echo -e "Press 0 if you don't like it, font will be deleted"
    read decision
    if [ "$decision" = "0" ]; then
        rm "/usr/share/figlet/$line"
        echo -e "Font deleted"
    else
        echo -e "Font saved"
    fi
    n=$((n+1))
done < $filename
```

Answer (score 3):

The original problem, is that content of your file list is being fed to `read decision` and `while` cycle doesn't work as you expect.
Though why do you need a list at all?

Better to iterate through files with `for` cycle.

```
#!/bin/bash
for font in /usr/share/figlet/*; do
    figlet -f "$font" Figlet
    echo -e "Press 0 if you don't like it, font will be deleted"
    read decision
    if [ "$decision" = "0" ]; then
        rm "$font"
        echo -e "Font deleted"
    else
        echo -e "Font saved"
    fi
done
```

Comment: @FCW If one of the answers solved your issue, please take a moment to [accept it](//$$SITEURL/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on [the checkmark on the left](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/203101). That will mark the question as answered and is the way that thanks are conveyed on the Stack Exchange sites.